# Installing custom apps offline on RHEL

Tags: rhel, software-installation, package-management

I installed and configured some apps (Airflow with PostgreSQL) on my Linux machine with the internet connection and I want to do the same with machines of my colleagues without the internet connection. I can do it manually by shipping source files and installing them but I find it inconvenient.

Is there a way to pack my configured apps to an archive and install them on another machine without the internet with just one command? It would be nice if the method also supported specifying a prefix for an installation folder.

The system my colleagues use is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo). It has minimal setup and for some reason yum is not working there.